Using 尊敬語 and 謙譲語 without 丁寧語?
When talking to a close friend you don't use 丁寧語 with, but you talk about somebody like your teacher. Would you then use 尊敬語 forms but without 丁寧語. Something like,
"あした、先生は召し上がる."

This is not very common, but possible. It heavily depends on the speaker's age, the speaker's character, and the balance between the casualness of the conversation and the level of respect you need to maintain.
Among high school students or younger, they usually do not bother to use honorific verbs when talking informally about their teacher. For example, they would simply say, "先生来たよ" or "先生昨日ラーメン食べたって".
On the other hand, when two adults casually talk about the actions of someone with a very high status, a mix of plain form and 尊敬語/謙譲語 verbs may happen. For example, it's entirely possible to say "昨日社長がいらっしゃったんだけどさー" or "昨日お客様にお会いしたら◯◯って仰ってたんだよ".
